# zf2 translate validators messages with variables

Tags: zend-framework2

I have custom message like this:

```
'options' => array(
    'min' => $min,
    'max' => $date->format('Y-m-d'),
    'inclusive' => true,
    'messages' => array(
        Between::NOT_BETWEEN => "The input is not between '%min%' and '%max%', inclusively",
    ),
),
```

I put this string in `.po` file and generate `.mo`, but message won't translate. For all other messages without variables it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read [in the ZF2 official documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.messages.html#using-pre-translated-validation-messages) on how to do this.

The translation files for validators are located at `/resources/languages`. You should simply attach a translator to `Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator` using these resource files or in your case your own file for your custom messages.

```
$validator->setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```

### EDIT

*I misinterpreted your question, here an edit*

Can you not translate the message before binding the variables like this:

```
$translator = ...translator...

'options' => array(
    'min' => $min,
    'max' => $date->format('Y-m-d'),
    'inclusive' => true,
    'messages' => array(
        Between::NOT_BETWEEN => $translator->translate(
            "The input is not between '%min%' and '%max%', inclusively"
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: do you read my last sentence? I put this string in .po file and generate .mo, but message won't translate. For all other messages without variables it's working fine. so it means that i read documentation and do so. the only problem appear when is with variables.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been nice,  if you had given more explanation.
Generally If string contains variables , You have to replace them with string formatters.

In your case msgid "The input is not between %s and %s"

I hope it should solve your problem.

Comment: i try it before to ask here, no translation happens